# Dropbox sync: deleting files locally and not from dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I assume that if I select for a specific folder not to be synced with my computer anymore I will be able to delete that folder from my dropbox folder(on my computer) without worry of it being deleted from my dropbox account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Dropbox tray icon > Preferences > Advanced > Selective Sync**, you can choose which folders to be synced. All non-sync folders can be safely removed.