# How to keep files once deleted from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

It seems I've used up all my space on Dropbox and they keep wanting me to upgrade instead of deleting files. What I did was transfer "My Documents" file and "My Pictures" file to dropbox not realizing that that would take up all of my Dropbox space. So I decided to delete the files from Dropbox to make more room. BUT I then realized that Dropbox deleted all the files from my computer and moved them to my Recycling Bin. I still want to keep the files but when I Restore the files, just wanting to restore them to my computer, it also restores the files back in Dropbox, to. How do I get around this dilema? Thanks, Tommy

Comment: This is the opposite problem, but the solution should be what you want (eg, just stop syncing): http://superuser.com/questions/714679/dropbox-sync-deleting-files-locally-and-not-from-dropbox

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Recycle Bin restore function.  Instead, Explore the Recycle Bin (Right Click and select Open) as you would any other folder.  There you can cut/paste the files into a new folder on your computer that isn't set to sync with Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

To keep local copies of your files, simply move those files out of your Dropbox folder into some other folder on your system.  Dropbox will automatically remove its online copies when it synchronizes your (now empty) folder.